# Does the VSCode extension API allow an extension to store data or maintain any state?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The extension I've built relies entirely on retrieving data from the document every time it needs to do something, and I can't seem to find a way to store even small pieces of data that would be useful to retrieve the next time a particular user task is run, rather than having to parse the document again and again. In all my digging, I can't find anything relevant.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're after. If it's just at runtime, you could just store it in a variable somewhere? Or do you mean persisting something to the disk?

Comment: Persisting was exactly the word I was looking for. And it doesn't have to be on disk necessarily. The way I've built my extension, running a task does a bunch of stuff after reading the doc, but the next time I run that task, I have to read it again. I'm wondering if there is a way I can persist information of the lifetime of the window, whether in memory or on disk

Comment: Can't you just store it in a variable you declare somewhere?

Comment: In the runtime of the app, instances of my code are run. However, they are one-off tasks, and any runtime variables inside of them are gone the next time the that the task is run. It starts from scratch. Is it possible to create global or static variables that exist outside the scope of the task?

Comment: Yes, that shouldn't be a problem, have you tried doing that? Could you share a code example?

Answer (score 1):

Most definitely. When your extension starts, you get a `context` in your `activate()` call. This context has various items to help you.

For small, key-value settings, you can use:

- `workspaceState`
- `globalState`

For anything larger, you have folders that you can store files in:

- `storageUri`
- `globalStorageUri`
- `logUri`